# Progress dialog theme changed automatically when changed activity to transparent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-progressbar

I have a progress bar in my activity ,it works fine to show  a download/upload progress .I have changed my activity in to a transperant activity.So that i have changed the theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
```

Then my progress dialog's theme becomes

This to

[image]

This

[image]

I am a beginner and i dont know how this happened ,i want to recover the first theme for progress dialog instead the old theme(second pic).Can anybody help me out please?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog's theme is being overridden by theme of Activity. So when you change it to transparent, you are changing the parent also, and this is reflecting to dialog also.

So you can give specific theme to dialog programatically

like

```
new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog);
```

Comment: I have tried this but it shows can not resolve symbol AppCompat ?Thanx for the reply

Comment: @Jennifer Updated the answer. Retest.

Comment: @Jennifer : Thank you Pankaj Kumar ,it's working. :) :) :)

Comment: @Jennifer Yes you can set. There is one constructor for the same as 'protected AlertDialog (Context context, int theme)'

Comment: Thank you Pankaj Kumar :) :).